WordPress Gutenberg Block Validation Failed: Attribute Mismatch on Re-edit
I'm developing a custom Gutenberg block for WordPress using the @wordpress/create-block package. The block allows users to add a testimonial with an image, name, position, and testimonial text. The block works fine on initial creation, but when I try to edit it again, I encounter a block validation error.
Error Message:
Block validation: Block validation failed for create-block/testimonial (Object1).
Expected attributes Array(1), instead saw Array(2)

Array(1)
["class", "testimonial-image", true]

Array(2)
["class", "testimonial-image", true]

["src", "http://test-1.local/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/some_profile_picture.jpeg", true]

Object
block.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "create-block/testimonial",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Testimonial",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "attributes": {
        "imageUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "attribute",
            "selector": "img.testimonial-image",
            "attribute": "src"
        },
        "testimonial": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "blockquote.testimonial-quote p"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div.testimonial-name"
        },
        "position": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div.testimonial-position"
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "testimonial",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
}

edit.tsx:
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps, MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';
import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { imageUrl, testimonial, name, position } = attributes;

    const onSelectImage = (media) => {
        setAttributes({ imageUrl: media.url });
    };

    const onChangeTestimonial = (value) => {
        setAttributes({ testimonial: value });
    };

    const onChangeName = (value) => {
        setAttributes({ name: value });
    };

    const onChangePosition = (value) => {
        setAttributes({ position: value });
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <div className="testimonial-block">
                <div className="testimonial-inner">
                    <div className="testimonial-content">
                        <div className="testimonial-image-wrapper">
                            <div className="testimonial-image-container">
                                {imageUrl ? (
                                    <img
                                        className="testimonial-image"
                                        src={imageUrl}
                                        alt={__('Testimonial image', 'testimonial')}
                                    />
                                ) : (
                                    <div className="testimonial-image-placeholder">
                                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                                            <MediaUpload
                                                onSelect={onSelectImage}
                                                allowedTypes={['image']}
                                                render={({ open }) => (
                                                    <Button onClick={open} className="button button-large">
                                                        {__('Upload Image', 'testimonial')}
                                                    </Button>
                                                )}
                                            />
                                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                {imageUrl && (
                                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                                        <MediaUpload
                                            onSelect={onSelectImage}
                                            allowedTypes={['image']}
                                            value={imageUrl}
                                            render={({ open }) => (
                                                <Button onClick={open} className="button button-large">
                                                    {__('Change Image', 'testimonial')}
                                                </Button>
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="testimonial-text-container">
                            <figure className="testimonial-figure">
                                <blockquote className="testimonial-quote">
                                    <RichText
                                        tagName="p"
                                        value={testimonial}
                                        onChange={onChangeTestimonial}
                                        placeholder={__('Testimonial text...', 'testimonial')}
                                    />
                                </blockquote>
                                <figcaption className="testimonial-caption">
                                    <div className="testimonial-name">
                                        <RichText
                                            tagName="div"
                                            value={name}
                                            onChange={onChangeName}
                                            placeholder={__('Name', 'testimonial')}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="testimonial-position">
                                        <RichText
                                            tagName="div"
                                            value={position}
                                            onChange={onChangePosition}
                                            placeholder={__('Position', 'testimonial')}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

save.tsx:
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import React from 'react';

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const { imageUrl, testimonial, name, position } = attributes;

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <div className="testimonial-block">
                <div className="testimonial-inner">
                    <div className="testimonial-content">
                        <div className="testimonial-image-wrapper">
                            <div className="testimonial-image-container">
                                <img
                                    className="testimonial-image"
                                    src={imageUrl || ''}
                                    alt=""
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="testimonial-text-container">
                            <figure className="testimonial-figure">
                                <blockquote className="testimonial-quote">
                                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={testimonial} />
                                </blockquote>
                                <figcaption className="testimonial-caption">
                                    <div className="testimonial-name">
                                        <RichText.Content tagName="div" value={name} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="testimonial-position">
                                        <RichText.Content tagName="div" value={position} />
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Error Description:

On initial creation, the block works as expected.
On attempting to edit the block, the block validation fails and all saved attributes are missing.
The error indicates an attribute mismatch, specifically with the class attribute for the image.

Steps Taken:

Ensured attributes are correctly defined in block.json.
Verified the structure of HTML output by save function matches the stored content.
Added logging to check attributes, which confirms attributes are missing during re-edit.

Question:
How can I resolve this block validation error and ensure the attributes are correctly retained and matched on re-edit? Any insights or suggestions are appreciated.

The issue is caused by the attribute selectors in block.json for name and position not matching the saved content.
If you look at the error your block triggers in the browser console, you can narrow down the cause to extra wrappers divs that don't match:
Content generated by save function:
...
    <div class="testimonial-name">
        <div>
            <div>John Doe</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-position">
        <div>
            <div>Manager</div>
        </div>
    </div>
...

Content retrieved from post body:
...
    <div class="testimonial-name">
        <div>John Doe</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-position">
        <div>Manager</div>
    </div>
...

Solution:
Update the selectors in block.json to match the div structure that is generated by your save() function:
...
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": ".testimonial-name div",
        },
        "position": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": ".testimonial-position div",
        }
...

Note: the difference is "div.className" should be ".className div" to select the html content of the inner div wrapper.
